# Is it possible to make a NSBox clickable (like a NSButton) in Swift macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbutton, nsbox

I have a NSBox with some labels inside it, that I want to act as a button. Is this possible, or do I have to find some other way to make large areas of an application clickable?

Comment: Please read the documentation of [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview) – especially the *Subclassing Notes* – which `NSBox` is a subclass of.

Answer (score 2):

As a subclass of `NSView`, `NSBox` responds to the `mouseDown` event. More information at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1524634-mousedown

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the func mouseDown event. You can also do this based on location. Also, if you’re working with the sks file you can always create a transparent button on top (assuming the box with labels is stationary)...